How to ensure the current passes through decoupling capacitor?
I am familiar with adding decoupling capacitors to protect input power pins of chips on PCBAs, as well as output power pins of voltage converters.
Still, there is something I am not sure of.
Below are two examples.
1)

Here is a chip U1 whose input power pin is decoupled with CAP1 and CAP2. The input voltage comes from a power plane on an inner layer, and the current is coming through the vias.
2)

Here is another example of a DC-DC, U1, whose output pin, after going through an inductor, is decoupled with CAP1, CAP2 and CAP3, and going through the vias in the bottom left corner.
My understanding is that on example #1, only CAP1 is usefull, and in example #2, all caps are useless : indeed, the current can go directly through the vias without meeting the decoupling caps. If I wanted to ensure that the current goes through the caps, I would do something like this :

Here, placing the via close to the input pin would make the caps useless.
The thing is, I never see this layout integrated on boards, I always see placements like on examples #1 and #2.
What is your opinion on this ? Do I need to ensure that the current goes through the caps for them to be usefull, or are examples #1 and #2 good enough ?
Thanks.

A useful perspective shift: there is no sudden cutoff of "useful" vs. "useless". Only a matter of degree. How might you measure this degree?  What circuit parameters, if any, depend upon distance between components, trace length, etc.?

Also, please expand your screenshot into these directions: https://i.sstatic.net/ZOC9sYmS.png as shown, it is not possible to conclude how effective these capacitors are. The column of 5 vias could also connect to capacitors nearby, or on the other side, and we simply cannot know otherwise.


My understanding is that on example #1, only CAP1 is usefull,

Not true. Even though CAP2 is "off to the side", except at extremely high frequency (10's of GHz) the voltage at the top of the via or at the input pin of the IC can't change without charging or discharging CAP2. That means it can and will do its job of smoothing the voltage at the input pin of the IC.

in example #2, all caps are useless : indeed, the current can go directly through the vias without meeting the decoupling caps.

Again not true. These capacitors are close enough that the voltage at the tops of the vias can't change without charging or discharging the capacitors. Therefore they can and will do their job (in combination with the inductor) of filtering the output of what is presumably a power supply circuit.

The physical position of the caps is important only in so much that the resistance and inductance of the connections to them are kept at a minimum.
You will notice in your second example that the caps are connected to inputs and outputs by a large pad of copper instead of thin tracks.
This achieves the objective of reducing inductance and resistance while not demanding that the capacitors are physically between source and sink.


Here is a chip U1 whose input power pin is decoupled with CAP1 and
CAP2. The input voltage comes from a power plane on an inner layer,
and the current is coming through the vias.

You are misunderstanding things.
The capacitors supply the impulses of current needed by the chip; they have the ability to do this and, they are there so that the current impulses are sourced very locally (by the capacitors). This means that there is very little impulse current supplied by the power planes through the vias. In fact, what we want is only an average top-up current to come through the vias to reduce EMI. So, for minimal EMI, the capacitors supply the big impulses of current that might be needed by the associated chip. Both capacitors are useful.

in example #2, all caps are useless : indeed, the current can go
directly through the vias without meeting the decoupling caps.

That is entirely incorrect.
The capacitors smooth the voltage on that node. They soak up the energy transferred from the inductor and keep ripple voltage low (a desired thing). The position of the via (that transfers the resulting smoothed voltage to the power plane) is perfectly fine where it is (or indeed where you propose it to be).
